# Any problems with having blanks between words in my xcode project name or files?

Tags: ios, xcode, project

Am I going to encounter any problems if my xcode project name has spaces in it like "*U S Maps To Go*"?

This includes any problems with file names like my sqlite database file name?

Thanks

Comment: My guess is that something will bite you somewhere.

Comment: Just use underscores if you're genuinely worried.  But then change the CFBundleDisplayName to make the name normal on the device.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a problem when it comes to working with Frameworks, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27335184/2359049).