# Parse/Parse.h file not found after update with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, xcode6, cocoapods

I tried everything I could imagine to fix this issue... Please help!

After updating to Xcode 6.4 and Parse SDK 1.7.5 I'm getting build error:

```
"Parse/Parse.h file not found"
```

Here's my Podfile:

```
target 'TV Admin' do
   pod 'RETableViewManager', '~> 1.6'
   pod 'SDNetworkActivityIndicator'
   pod 'Motif'
   pod 'Parse', '~> 1.7' 
end
```

All Cocoapods dependencies except Parse are working great.
Here's .xcworkspace view:
[image]

I'm using Cocoapods 0.38.0.beta.2

Thanks.

Comment: I'm Having exactly the same Issue... After updating to 0.38 beta 2, the Parse only stopped working... I think it's a bug within cocoa pods and maybe any pod that is used as a library. Do you have any other library as a pod or only Parse? All my other pods have the code files.

Comment: I'm having the same issue

Comment: Its really use full answer :- http://stackoverflow.com/a/42486383/3752143 Its work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the problem was in `podspec` file. Parse team updated it to 1.7.5.3 for Parse, ParseFacebookUtils, ParseCrashReporting and now everything works great.

Now simply running `pod update` should fix the issue.

[Here's the original post on official developers group.](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/parse-developers/4tBH3gkfnX4/9d8Lk55kD9AJ)

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this issue after updating XCode to 6.4 today. 
Taking a look at the Search Frameworks showed that they were empty after the XCode update. 
So change the Framework Search Paths in Project -> Build Settings -> Framework Search Paths and Add $(SRCROOT)     (recursive)
That fixed it for me.

Comment: This worked for me as well, but it bothers me that it became needed suddenly.

Comment: This solved the Parse.h issue, but now I get 'Bolts/BFTask.h' file not found…